# Create 8760 dataframe with hourly resolution timestamps

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

A bit of a naive question.  I want to create a `dataframe` that spans a full calendar year in hourly resolution (8760 values).  How can I manipulate the following lines from a tutorial to pull data from the previous year.

```
start = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today(), tz=time_zone) #used for testing
end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=365) #to get all day values
```

Essentially I want to replace `today()` with 1/1/2016, and then pull historical forecasted values for my analysis.

Answer (score 3):

You can build `start` by subtracting a year from whatever your end date is:

```
date_str = '1/1/2016'
start = pd.to_datetime(date_str) - pd.Timedelta(days=365)
hourly_periods = 8760
drange = pd.date_range(start, periods=hourly_periods, freq='H')
```

Then when you're ready to make a data frame, set `index=drange`, e.g.:

```
# toy example data
data = list(range(len(drange)))

# create data frame with drange index
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=drange)
```

See Pandas docs for [date_range](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and [Timedeltas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) for more.